# 3D numpy array in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, theano, keras

I'm having a 3D NumpyArray which I want to through in a Keras Neural Network.

Because of one hot encoding the array became a 3D array.

```
    [
    [[0,1,0,0], [1,0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0,1], [1,1,0,0]],
    [[0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]]
    ]
```

Since Keras can only compute 2D arrays, my question is, how can I reduce the dimensionality and use it into a sequencial keras NN?

I currently get the error:

```
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "D:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\backend\\theano_backend.py:503"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 2, got 3 with shape (32L, 10L, 12L).')
```

Comment: Please post what you'd like the 2D array to be (and use a range of numbers, not just 0s and 1s, so we can see the unique solution you want).

Comment: I use one hot encoding. Theres no sense in a higher range of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.ndarray.flatten` to make it into a `1D` array. Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(
    [
        [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
    ]
    )
a.flatten()
```

From this, if you want to split it by row, I'd recommend doing

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(
    [
        [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0]],
        [[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
    ]
    )
a = map(np.ndarray.flatten, a)
```

Comment: Thank you, but Theano just eats 2D arrays.